# Comprobar si, dados 2 números enteros, uno es mayor que otro; mediante función recursiva

Tags: c++

Modele mediante una función matemática y diseñe un programa recursivo que dados dos números enteros no negativos m y n, indique si el primer numero m es mayor estrictamente que el segundo número n, que utilice sólo el operador de comparación de la igualdad (==), la función sucesor (sumar 1), la función predecesor (restar 1) y la estructura condicional (if, if-else).

No entiendo cual sería el caso base para hacerlo esto es lo que he intentado pero no funciona.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool mayor(int m, int n);

int main()
{
    int m;
    int n;
    cout<< mayor(m,n) << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool mayor(int m, int n){
if(m==n){
    return 0;
}
else{if(m==mayor(m,n+1)){
   return 0;
        }else{
        return 1;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Siguiendo [¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1656/edit), he editado el título para facilitar las búsquedas a futuros usuarios :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una respuesta más:
La clave la tome del enunciado:

> dados dos números enteros **no negativos** m y n, indique si el primer
>   numero m es mayor estrictamente que el segundo número n. 
>   por lo tanto el valor de comparación 0 es valido en tanto tienen que ser *no
>   negativos*

y ademas

> sólo el operador de comparación de la igualdad (==), **la función
>   sucesor** (sumar 1), **la función predecesor** (restar 1) y la estructura
>   condicional (if, if-else)

como tenia que usar ambas la respuesta que se me ocurrió simula un *acercamiento mutuo*

por ejemplo si los números son 10 y 5 por cada llamada los números se irían acercando

mayor (10, 5);

(10, 5) -> 9 == 5?  no -> 9 == 6?  no

llama a mayor (9,6);

(9, 6) -> 8 == 6? no -> 8 == 7?  no

llama a mayor(8,7)

(8, 7) -> 7 == 7? si return true;

y en caso que mayor sea igual o menor a menor, mayor tendria que restarse hasta cero, en cuyo caso retorna falso

```
#include <iostream>

bool mayor (int m, int n);
int main ()
{
    int m ;
    int n ;
    std::cout<< mayor(m,n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

bool mayor (int m, int n)
{
    if (m == 0) 
        return false;
    else
    {
        m--;
        if ( m == n ) return true;
        else
        {
            n++;
            if (m == n) return true;
            else return mayor (m,n);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: La idea **es la correcta**. **Pero ...** tiene un fallo. `mayor( 1000000, 10 )` provoca `Violación de segmento`. Dale solución, y tienes mi voto (y espero que un merecido *Respuesta Aceptada*.

Comment: Perfecto, déjame revisarlo

Comment: Vale. Comprobado. Tu solución, **tal y como está**, **ES LA CORRECTA**. El problema lo tienes al no aplicar *Tail-Recursion Optimization*. Si se compila con `g++ -O2`, funciona perfectamente, incluso para números grandes ( `m = 10000000, n = 1` ). +1

Comment: En serio, espero que te la acepten. Muy buena idea :-)

Comment: El problema de `Violación de segmento` será aplicable a todos las soluciones (incluida la mía) si no se aplica la optimización.

Comment: Si, comprendo, es por el número de  llamadas a la función recursiva y depende de los numeros dados.. por ejemplo en tu solucion tales números (10000000, 10) solo llamaría a la funcion 10 veces. (no hay problema) pero si llama a (10000000, 10000010) causaría el error, pero mi solucion llamaría solo 10 ;)

Comment: Correcto. Es el mismo *problema* en **todas** las soluciones, cuando el número de llamadas es *demasiado* grande. En G++, se soluciona haciendo `-O2`. En otros compiladores, puede *no fallar* (es una optimización del compilador, no forma parte de ningún estándar), o necesitar algún *flag* concreto.

Answer (score 4):

Esta respuesta **si es válida**. Solo usa `==` y `+ 1`.

Pero que conste que la otra me gustaba mas ;-)

```
#include <iostream>

int mayor( int m, int n, int idx ) {
  if( ( idx == m ) && ( idx == n ) )
    return 0; // iguales.

  if( idx == m )
    return -1; // m es menor.

  if( idx == n )
    return 1; // n es mayor.

  return mayor( m, n, idx + 1 );
}

int main( void ) {
  int a = 10,
      b = 20,
      ret = mayor( a, b, 0 );

  std::cout << "m: " << a << ", n: " << b << "; ";

  if( ret == 0 )
    std::cout << "son iguales.";
  else if( ret == -1 )
    std::cout << "m es menor.";
  else
    std::cout << "m es mayor.";

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

El funcionamiento es simple: *simulamos* un bucle de incremento infinito.

Iniciamos llamando a `mayor( )` con su último argumento a `0`, y lo comparamos con los otros 2. Si no se cumple ninguna condición, sencillamente **nos llamamos recursivamente, haciendo `+ 1` al último argumento**.

Es *funcionamente equivalente* a hacer

```
int idx = 0;

while( true ) {
  if( ALGO ) break;
  if( OTRO ALGO ) break;

  ++ idx;
}
```

Es un simple bucle infinito, en el que aumentamos el valor de la variable `idx`.

Es **importante** mantener el cuerpo de la función `mayor( )` **tal y como esta**. El orden de las comparaciones es importante (primero, la igualdad con **ambos** argumentos, después los casos específicos).

También **muy importante**, para evitar problemas si los argumentos son *grandes*, mantener el último `return mayor( m, n, idx + 1 )` tal y como está, sin usar mas variables internas, para que el compilador optimize la llamada recursiva y no tengamos problemas con pasarnos con el tamaño de la pila.

Comment: Podrías explicar como funciona?

Comment: @ElPatrón solo suma 1 en cada iteración a una variable que luego compara contra ambos números, al primer número que llegue significa que ese es el menor, o si llega a ambos, entonces son iguales.

Comment: @ElPatrón editado, pero es tal y como dice JYass.

Answer (score 3):

El algoritmo es prácticamente el mismo que el propuesto por @Trauma. Después de todo hemos llegado a la misma conclusión.

La diferencia está en que según el enunciado la función únicamente debe indicar si `m` es estrictamente mayor que `n` y yo me he centrado en facilitar únicamente dicha información, obviando el resto.

```
#include <iomanip>  // std::boolalpha
#include <iostream>

bool mayor(const int m, const int n, const int test=0)
{
  if( test == m)
    return false;
  else if( test == n)
    return true;

  return mayor(m,n,test+1);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha      // para imprimir falso/verdadero
            << mayor(5,5) << '\n'  // falso
            << mayor(4,5) << '\n'  // falso
            << mayor(6,5) << '\n'; // verdadero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahí te va un ejemplo, este es diferente al tuyo.

```
int menor(int, int, int);
int mayor(int, int, int);
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    cout<<"ingrese tres numeros\n";
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    cout<<"el menor es: "<<menor(a,b,c)<<endl;
    cout<<"el mayor es: "<<mayor(a,b,c)<<endl;
    cin.ignore();return 0;
}
int menor(int a,int b,int c)
{
    if(a<b) b=a;
    if(a<c) c=a;
    if(b<c) c=b;
return c;
}
int mayor(int a,int b,int c)
{
    if(a>b) b=a;
    if(a>c) c=a;
    if(b>c) c=b;
return c;
}
```

Comment: En la pregunta indica `sólo el operador de comparación de la igualdad (==)`. Tu respuesta usa los operadores `<` y `>`.

Comment: A ver ahora si revisen por favor... http://cpp.sh/

Comment: @Ric_hc , la pregunta del **OP**,  especifica **recursividad** y **NO** emplear los operadores `<`,  `>` y su respuesta  no hace eso.